# RN Component syntax

Tags: react-native

Can anyone point a direction of the Component syntax using the latest React-Native init cmd? I don't recall ES6 class syntax quite like it.

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {

}
```

Where, I've seen the following without brackets.

```
export default class App extends Component {

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reference : https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

```
class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>;
 }
}
```

This is the ES6 way of defining components in react.

Comment: my question is really on the Component<{}> part, instead. What does <{}> syntax mean?